# Fullcalendar - Events with 00

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

The events have 00 before the text (00myeventname).

this is my code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ //re-initialize the calendar
     header: h,
     buttonIcons: false, // show the prev/next text
     editable: false,
     droppable: false,
     lang: 'pt',
     events: 'http://nameit.pt/pontotestes/calendarevents'
});
```

Could you help me?

Comment: What exactly would you like help with? What is your question?

Comment: How can i remove the 00? why fullcalendar  shows 00?

Comment: You need to provide more context for us to be able to help you. Please also provide the corresponding HTML code.

Comment: the problem is that the tittle of events have 00 at the beggining.

Comment: <div id="calendar" class="has-toolbar">
         </div>

Comment: The code works if you remove `header: h,` from the above. However, the URL to your events is broken. Apparently, that script is expecting a request variable called `data` and is not finding it, therefore failing.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/F9zWw/1/ for what I am seeing.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone hits this again. You have to set timeFormat in options to empty string:

```
timeFormat: ''
```

Or simply set the event data to:

```
allDay: true
```

See this:
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/timeFormat/